# How to access remotely a web service hosted with IIS .NET V4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I created a web service using Visual Studio 2017 that is hosted on a remote machine (a remote server) using IIS with .NET V4.5.

The web service publishing to IIS was done using IIS Manager.

I am not able to change the "IP address" to something else than "All Unassigned". If I select the IP address available on the drop down menu, then the web site doesn't work (returning error: "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.").

If I use "All Unassigned" with "host name" "localhost", it works well locally.

Which means that I can enter the url (http://localhost:81/RestServiceImpl.svc) in a web browser and it execute the web service as expected.

My question is: how can I host my web service on this remote machine so that I can then access it from any computer using the url where localhost would be replaced by the remote machine IP address?

See below my web.config file (it could be that I'm not using the right binding, or that the remote machine IP address is hidden):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="RsConnString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|RestDB.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
                    <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                </endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
      <add name=".svc" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, &#xD;&#xA;System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                                                                                                   />
    </handlers>

    <!--
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <modules>
      <remove name="ServiceModel" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Comment: Open the firewall to allow incoming traffic to port 81.  That port will usually be blocked by default.  All Unassigned should work for both localhost or the real host name if the correct firewall port is open.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your answer. I created an inbound rule (tried it with port 80 and 81) following the procedure at that link (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043(v=sql.110).aspx) but I still can't connect remotely. Also note that on the remote machine, the url works only with localhost:80 (not when I replace localhost with the ip address).

Comment: @Nathan Also, what do you mean by "the real host name"? When I put anything other than localhost it does not work.

Comment: Are you using "localhost" in the binding config hostname?  If so, leave the hostname blank in the bindings and set it to All Unassigned.  The hostname in the bindings is for virtual hosting, which shouldn't apply to what you are trying to do at this time.